# Sample for using Graph# in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, graph

Can anyone point me to an example of **how to use [Graph#](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/)** via [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) in a **winforms** application (c#).

Especially loading *.gml - files and showing the Graph-control.

**Any help appreciated**.

Comment: Maybe you should ask the guy (Palez the project coordinator) who said it can be done that way in this thread: http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/discussions/58000

Comment: @Jeremy: I think I figuered it out by myself. Some more post and my brain did the trick...

Comment: Great stuff mate, please post the trick or bare bone example. If you did that I'm sure you'd get more than the +50 bounty on offer from upvotes

Comment: @Jeremy: I will do it, maybe all code is too much, but the main abstract should do well...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic idea is to create a WPF user control, that encapsulates a Graph # canvas. This user control is what you would then display in the ElementHost.

I have put together a small sample application that demonstrates this by basically exposing the GraphSharp.Sample.TestCompoundLayout window as user control.

http://cl.ly/0w350230200g0w0o2R2N

I also added loading from GML files which basically boils down to this function:

```
        var graph = new CompoundGraph<object, IEdge<object>>();

        try
        {
            //open the file of the graph
            var reader = XmlReader.Create(fileName);

            //create the serializer
            var serializer = new GraphMLDeserializer<object, IEdge<object>, CompoundGraph<object, IEdge<object>>>();


            //deserialize the graph
            serializer.Deserialize(reader, graph,
                                   id => id, (source, target, id) => new Edge<object>(source, target)
                );

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        layout.Graph = graph;
        layout.UpdateLayout();
```

Comment: Which control from GraphSharp did you take ?

Comment: If you have a look at the complete source code in the answer, you will find the GraphSharpControl.xaml / GraphSharpControl.xaml.cs that is the WPF user control. It basically is a reframed GraphShapr.Sampl.TestCompountLayout file. The layout element referenced in the code snippet above is defined in the XAML as: 

        <Controls:ZoomControl>
            <graph:GraphLayout x:Name="layout" />
        </Controls:ZoomControl>

Comment: thanks a lot! I did ask my question primary for helping some others out there and just in cas, your sample code will be unavailable in some future time...